# Make canvas unselectable

Tags: html, canvas, selection

I have a canvas onto which I am drawing a JavaScript game. The problem is that when the player moves the mouse, half the time they end up selecting the canvas which looks ugly.

I have tried googling around and using some CSS like -webkit-user-select: none; and variants, but nothing seems to work with a canvas.

Comment: Please provide an example. A normal canvas element shouldn't be able to be selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not that canvas is selectable, but that you're not telling the browser that you want mouse used exclusively for your game.

In your `mousedown`/`mouseup`/`click` handlers you should run `event.preventDefault()` or `return false`.

You should do the same thing in keyboard events to avoid colliding with keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

`canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }`